# Chart (grafico) con varios datos c#

Tags: c#, mvc, aplicación-web

resulta que tengo un chart en el cual debo listar aprox 200 datos y ya al llegar a aprox 40 datos, se desarma el chart, hay alguna forma de dar next page y saltar a otros datos y mostrarlos en el mismo grafico? u alguna forma de poder listar las aprox 200 datos que tengo?, envio una foto. Trabajo con C# MVC, trabaje con este grafico y solo le inserte datos dinamicos para probar:

http://www.macoratti.net/17/11/mvc_chartjs1.htm

adjunto foto de como se ve:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es el codigo de la vista:

```
    <div class="card mb-3">
                <div class="card-header">
                    <i class="fas fa-chart-area"></i>
                    Cantidad De Incidencias
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-12">
                            <div class="panel panel-primary list-panel" id="list-panel">
                                <div class="panel-heading list-panel-heading">
                                </div>
                                <div class="panel-body">
                                    <h2>Gráfico </h2>

                                    @using (Html.BeginForm("BusquedaFilter", "FiltroController", null, FormMethod.Post))
                                    {
                                        <div Style="font-family: Corbel; font-size: small ;text-align:center " class="row">
                                            <div>
                                                <div style="width:900px;height:400px">
                                                    <canvas id="mChart1" style="padding: 0;margin: auto;display: block; "> </canvas>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div Style="font-family: Corbel; font-size: small ;text-align:center; " class="row">
                                            <div>
                                            </div>
                                            <div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    }
                                    </div>
                            </div>
```

este es el codigo del controlador:

```
  [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult NuevoGrafico()
    {
        List<object> iDados = new List<object>();
        //Datatable 
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Columns.Add("Embozadora", System.Type.GetType("System.String"));
        dt.Columns.Add("Tarjetas emitidas", System.Type.GetType("System.Int32"));
        DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
        dr["Embozadora"] = "DatacardSD260";
        dr["Tarjetas emitidas"] = 105;
        dt.Rows.Add(dr);
        dr = dt.NewRow();
        dr["Embozadora"] = "DatacardCP60";
        dr["Tarjetas emitidas"] = 78;
        dt.Rows.Add(dr);
        dr = dt.NewRow();
        dr["Embozadora"] = "MaquinaNBSM20";
        dr["Tarjetas emitidas"] = 87;
        dt.Rows.Add(dr);
        dr = dt.NewRow();
        dr["Embozadora"] = "EvolisPrimacyBS";
        dr["Tarjetas emitidas"] = 67;
        dt.Rows.Add(dr);
        dr = dt.NewRow();
        dr["Embozadora"] = "EvolisPrimacyYN";
        dr["Tarjetas emitidas"] = 116;
        dt.Rows.Add(dr);
        dr = dt.NewRow();
        dr["Embozadora"] = "EvolisPrimacyCS";
        dr["Tarjetas emitidas"] = 116;
        dt.Rows.Add(dr);
        dr = dt.NewRow();
        dr["Embozadora"] = "EvolisPrimacyJP";
        dr["Tarjetas emitidas"] = 116;
        dt.Rows.Add(dr);
        dr = dt.NewRow();
        dr["Embozadora"] = "EvolisPrimacyRP";
        dr["Tarjetas emitidas"] = 116;
        dt.Rows.Add(dr);
        dr = dt.NewRow();
        dr["Embozadora"] = "EvolisPrimacySD";
        dr["Tarjetas emitidas"] = 116;
        dt.Rows.Add(dr);
        dr = dt.NewRow();
        dr["Embozadora"] = "EvolisPrimacyY45";
        dr["Tarjetas emitidas"] = 116;
        dt.Rows.Add(dr);
        dr = dt.NewRow();
        dr["Embozadora"] = "EvolisPrimacyYN1";
        dr["Tarjetas emitidas"] = 116;
        dt.Rows.Add(dr);
        dr = dt.NewRow();
        dr["Embozadora"] = "EvolisPrimacyYN2";
        dr["Tarjetas emitidas"] = 116;
        dt.Rows.Add(dr);
        dr = dt.NewRow();
        dr["Embozadora"] = "EvolisPrimacyYN3";
        dr["Tarjetas emitidas"] = 116;
        dt.Rows.Add(dr);
        dr = dt.NewRow();
        dr["Embozadora"] = "EvolisPrimacyYN4";
        dr["Tarjetas emitidas"] = 116;
        dt.Rows.Add(dr);
        dr = dt.NewRow();
        dr["Embozadora"] = "EvolisPrimacyYN5";
        dr["Tarjetas emitidas"] = 116;
        dt.Rows.Add(dr);
        dr = dt.NewRow();
        dr["Embozadora"] = "EvolisPrimacyYN6";
        dr["Tarjetas emitidas"] = 116;
        dt.Rows.Add(dr);
        dr = dt.NewRow();
        dr["Embozadora"] = "EvolisPrimacyYN7";
        dr["Tarjetas emitidas"] = 116;
        dt.Rows.Add(dr);
        dr = dt.NewRow();
        dr["Embozadora"] = "EvolisPrimacyYN8";
        dr["Tarjetas emitidas"] = 116;
        dt.Rows.Add(dr);
        dr = dt.NewRow();
        dr["Embozadora"] = "EvolisPrimacyYN9";
        dr["Tarjetas emitidas"] = 116;
        dt.Rows.Add(dr);
        dr = dt.NewRow();
        dr["Embozadora"] = "EvolisPrimacyYN0";
        dr["Tarjetas emitidas"] = 116;
        dt.Rows.Add(dr);
        dr = dt.NewRow();
        dr["Embozadora"] = "EvolisPrimacyYN11";
        dr["Tarjetas emitidas"] = 116;
        dt.Rows.Add(dr);
        dr = dt.NewRow();
        dr["Embozadora"] = "EvolisPrimacyYN12";
        dr["Tarjetas emitidas"] = 116;
        dt.Rows.Add(dr);
        dr = dt.NewRow();
        dr["Embozadora"] = "EvolisPrimacyYN21";
        dr["Tarjetas emitidas"] = 116;
        dt.Rows.Add(dr);
        dr = dt.NewRow();
        dr["Embozadora"] = "EvolisPrimacyYN22";
        dr["Tarjetas emitidas"] = 116;
        dt.Rows.Add(dr);
        dr = dt.NewRow();
        dr["Embozadora"] = "EvolisPrimacyYN23";
        dr["Tarjetas emitidas"] = 116;
        dt.Rows.Add(dr);
        dr = dt.NewRow();
        dr["Embozadora"] = "EvolisPrimacyYN24";
        dr["Tarjetas emitidas"] = 116;
        dt.Rows.Add(dr);
        dr = dt.NewRow();
        dr["Embozadora"] = "EvolisPrimacyYN25";
        dr["Tarjetas emitidas"] = 116;
        dt.Rows.Add(dr);
        dr = dt.NewRow();
        dr["Embozadora"] = "EvolisPrimacyYN26";
        dr["Tarjetas emitidas"] = 116;
        dt.Rows.Add(dr);
        dr = dt.NewRow();
        dr["Embozadora"] = "EvolisPrimacyYN27";
        dr["Tarjetas emitidas"] = 116;
        dt.Rows.Add(dr);
        dr = dt.NewRow();
        dr["Embozadora"] = "EvolisPrimacyYN28";
        dr["Tarjetas emitidas"] = 116;
        dt.Rows.Add(dr);
        dr = dt.NewRow();
        dr["Embozadora"] = "EvolisPrimacyYN29";
        dr["Tarjetas emitidas"] = 116;
        dt.Rows.Add(dr);
        dr = dt.NewRow();
        dr["Embozadora"] = "EvolisPrimacyYN30";
        dr["Tarjetas emitidas"] = 116;
        dt.Rows.Add(dr);
        dr = dt.NewRow();
        dr["Embozadora"] = "EvolisPrimacyYN31";
        dr["Tarjetas emitidas"] = 116;
        dt.Rows.Add(dr);
        dr = dt.NewRow();
        dr["Embozadora"] = "EvolisPrimacyYN32";
        dr["Tarjetas emitidas"] = 116;
        dt.Rows.Add(dr);
        dr = dt.NewRow();
        dr["Embozadora"] = "EvolisPrimacyYN33";
        dr["Tarjetas emitidas"] = 116;
        dt.Rows.Add(dr);
        dr = dt.NewRow();
        dr["Embozadora"] = "EvolisPrimacyYN34";
        dr["Tarjetas emitidas"] = 116;
        dt.Rows.Add(dr);
        dr = dt.NewRow();
        dr["Embozadora"] = "EvolisPrimacyYN35";
        dr["Tarjetas emitidas"] = 116;
        dt.Rows.Add(dr);
        dr = dt.NewRow();
        dr["Embozadora"] = "EvolisPrimacyYN36";
        dr["Tarjetas emitidas"] = 116;
        dt.Rows.Add(dr);
        dr = dt.NewRow();
        dr["Embozadora"] = "EvolisPrimacyYN37";
        dr["Tarjetas emitidas"] = 116;
        dt.Rows.Add(dr);
        dr = dt.NewRow();
        dr["Embozadora"] = "EvolisPrimacyYN38";
        dr["Tarjetas emitidas"] = 116;
        dt.Rows.Add(dr);
        dr = dt.NewRow();
        dr["Embozadora"] = "EvolisPrimacyYN39";
        dr["Tarjetas emitidas"] = 116;
        dt.Rows.Add(dr);
        dr = dt.NewRow();
        //coriendo y extrayendo cada datacolumn para el list<object>
        foreach (DataColumn dc in dt.Columns)
        {
            List<object> x = new List<object>();
            x = (from DataRow drr in dt.Rows select drr[dc.ColumnName]).ToList();
            iDados.Add(x);
        }
        //Datos retornados con JSON
        return Json(iDados, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

este es mi script:

```
    <script>
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/Home/NuevoGrafico",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (mems) {
            var aData = mems;
            var aLabels = aData[0];
            var aDatasets1 = aData[1];
            var dataT = {
                labels: aLabels,
                datasets: [{
                    label: "Embozadoras",
                    data: aDatasets1,
                    fill: false,
                    backgroundColor: ["rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)", "rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)", "rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)", "rgba(255, 205, 86, 0.2)", "rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)", "rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)", "rgba(201, 203, 207, 0.2)"],
                    borderColor: ["rgb(54, 162, 235)", "rgb(255, 99, 132)", "rgb(255, 159, 64)", "rgb(255, 205, 86)", "rgb(75, 192, 192)", "rgb(153, 102, 255)", "rgb(201, 203, 207)"],
                    borderWidth: 1
                }]
            };
            var ctx = $("#mChart1").get(0).getContext("2d");
            var myNewChart = new Chart(ctx, {
                type: 'bar',
                data: dataT,
                options: {
                    responsive: true,
                    title: { display: true, text: 'Cantidad de Tarjetas emitidas' },
                    legend: { position: 'bottom' },
                    scales: {
                        xAxes: [{ gridLines: { display: false }, display: true, scaleLabel: { display: false, labelString: '' } }],
                        yAxes: [{ gridLines: { display: false }, display: true, scaleLabel: { display: false, labelString: '' }, ticks: { stepSize: 50, beginAtZero: true } }]
                    },
                }
            });
        }
    });
</script>
```

}

este es mi layout:

```
    @{
    Layout = null;
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link href="~/Content/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="~/Content/bootstrap-theme.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="~/Content/CTable.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>@ViewBag.Title</title>
    @RenderSection("head", false)
    <style>
        .modal-content {
            width: 600px !important;
            margin: 30px auto !important;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container body-content">
        @RenderBody()
    </div>
    @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
</body>
</html>
```

Espero me haya explicado bien!, saludos.

Comment: Por favor, [edit] la pregunta y agregue el código fuente de la gráfica. Según esta [respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35935939/4092887) puedes intentar a través de estilos aplicar un scroll horizontal.

Comment: Listo @MauricioAriasOlave, ahi lo edite, gracias!

Comment: Si necesitas mostrar tantas columnas no crees que sería mejor mostrarlas en [forma Horizontal](https://www.chartjs.org/samples/latest/charts/bar/horizontal.html)?

Comment: @Killbunny, gracias por responder, como podria ordenarlo de forma horizontal?, igual son casi 200 columnas, no quedaria muy "largo" la vista?